# Table with different sized columns

Tags: tables

Is it possible to build tables with different sized columns and manage the vertical limits so it fits only the non-empty table cells? 
I know how to do this to horizontal lines (with `\cline`) but I don't know if it is possible to do it with columns.

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c | }:
```

...maybe I can change something here, no idea.

Thank you

PS: I can add my code but I think it's too confusing because of the several multilines and multicollumns but if you think it helps, I can do it.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You can say e.g. `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` to get rid of the vertical lines on each side of a particular column. (Or change `1` to `2` to apply to 2 columns.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn` with an argument, where `|` is removed (the tabular in my example is certainly not as big as in your example):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c | }
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
1&2&3&\multicolumn{3}{c}{}\\
\cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]